# About creating a User Defined Function (UDF) in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am beginner to Scala and wanted to learn about UDF in Spark Scala. 
I am going to  use following example demonstrate my problem. I am using Spark Scala using Data Bricks.

Lets say i have following data frame,

```
val someDF = Seq(
  (1, "bat"),
  (4, "mouse"),
  (3, "horse")
).toDF("number", "word")

someDF.show()

+------+-----+
|number| word|
+------+-----+
|     1|  bat|
|     4|mouse|
|     3|horse|
+------+-----+
```

I need to create a function to calculate a new column by doing some operations to the number column.

For an example i created this function to calculate 25/(number+1) as follows and it worked.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val caldf = udf { (df: Double) => (25/(df+1)) }

someDF.select($"number", $"word", caldf(col("number")) as "newc").show()
+------+-----+----+
|number| word|newc|
+------+-----+----+
|     1|  bat|12.5|
|     4|mouse| 5.0|
|     3|horse|6.25|
+------+-----+----+
```

**But when i tried this with the log operator, it didn't work**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val caldf = udf { (df: Double) => log(25/(df+1)) }




 command-3140852555505238:3: error: overloaded method value log with alternatives:
      (columnName: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
      (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column
     cannot be applied to (Double)
    val caldf = udf { (df: Double) => log(25/(df+1)) }
                                  ^
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what may be the reason ? Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need udf for the function in your question:

```
someDF.select($"number", $"word", log(lit(25) / (lit(1) + $"number")) as "newC")
```

If you insist on using udf though:

```
val caldf = udf { df: Double => math.log(25/(df+1)) }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But when i used the log operator like i mentioned in the question, the udf is not working. It gives the same error as i mentioned in the question .